# Switfmailer PHP script not working after switching hosting company

Tags: php, forms, email, hosting, swiftmailer

I'm using Swiftmailer for my website's contact form to send the form data via email when it's submitted.  I switched to a different hosting company and seemingly everything should be the same, but it no longer works.  I'm not getting any error messages.  I get status 200 OK when clicking "Submit."  I deleted and re-created the email account, but that didn't help.  Changed the SMTP authentication information to the new hosting comopany's server, but still no email is sent.  Any ideas?  Oh, and I switched from Bluehost to A2 hosting.  Thanks in advance.

Andrew

Comment: to which domain you are sending mail? gmail or something like that? If so check your spam, if you are checking on any outlook mail, check your administrator. You may need to whitelist the ip address

Answer (score 0):

1). Check the spam folder
2). Ensure sendmail is installed
3). If reaching to SPAM, allow your server IP in DNS SPF record